# SQL Server: Search all tables for GUID - Out Of Memory

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a need to clean some data from a database. I wrote a query to search through all the tables for a particular GUID.

The database that I have has around 400 tables and 2000 uniqueidentifier columns.

After running the query I get an error:

```
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

The query that I am using:

```
DECLARE @begin INT = 1
      , @end INT
      , @table VARCHAR(250)
      , @column VARCHAR(250)
      , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
      , @uniqueID nvarchar(100) = 'XXX'

SELECT @end = COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns.TABLE_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables.TABLE_NAME AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier'

WHILE @begin <= @end

BEGIN

;WITH ColumnID AS   (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME) AS ID
            , c.TABLE_SCHEMA
            , c.TABLE_NAME
            , c.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns c
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables t ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier'
    )

SELECT @table = TABLE_NAME, @column = COLUMN_NAME FROM ColumnID WHERE ID = @begin

SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @table + ''' AS ''Table Name'', ' + @column + ' AS ''Column Name'' FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE ' + @column + ' = ''' + @uniqueID + '''' 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

SET @begin = @begin + 1

END
```

**Question 1:**

*How can I solve this problem?*

The System.OutOfMemory error is due to returning too large set of a results to Grid for SSMS to handle. It is a client-side error, not SQL Server. When using a file everything works (right click the command pane, Results To -> File)

**Question 2:**

How can I change query to get one table with Table Name and Column Name as a result.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#_Results', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #_Results;

CREATE TABLE #_results (table_name  sysname, column_name sysname)

DECLARE @begin INT = 1, @end INT, @table VARCHAR(250), @column VARCHAR(250), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @uniqueID nvarchar(100) = 'XXX'

SELECT @end = COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns.TABLE_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables.TABLE_NAME AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier'

WHILE @begin <= @end
BEGIN

;WITH ColumnID AS   (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME) AS ID
            , c.TABLE_SCHEMA
            , c.TABLE_NAME
            , c.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns c
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables t ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier'
    )

SELECT @table = TABLE_NAME, @column = COLUMN_NAME FROM ColumnID WHERE ID = @begin

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #_results SELECT DISTINCT ''' + @table + ''' AS TableName, ''' + @column + ''' AS ColumnName FROM [' + @table + '] WHERE [' + @column + '] = ''' + @uniqueID + '''' ;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;

SET @begin = @begin + 1

END

SELECT * FROM #_results

DROP TABLE #_Results
```

Comment: The CTE results are static with regards to conditions within the loop, run it once into a table variable outside the loop, use that inside the loop.

Comment: The System.OutOfMemory error is due to returning too large of a results set for SSMS to handle.  It is a client-side error, not SQL Server.

Comment: DanGuzman is right - don't output the results to a grid, use a file instead, and you should be fine (right click the command pane, Results To -> File).

Comment: Dan Guzman is correct. And thank you Luaan! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how this would cause the out-of-memory error, but your SQL is:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @table + ''' AS ''Table Name'', ' + @column + ' AS ''Column Name'' FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE ' + @column + ' = ''' + @uniqueID + ''''
```

Try changing this to:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT ''' + @table + ''' AS TableName, ''' + @column + ''' AS ColumnName FROM [' + @table + '] WHERE [' + @column + '] = ''' + @uniqueID + '''' ;
```

This makes the following changes:

- Removes the spaces from your aliases.  These just make the SQL more confusing.
- Add single quotes around the column name.
- Add square braces around the table and column names, just in case they have non-conforming characters.

If that doesn't work, then replace:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

with:

```
SELECT @sql;
```

to see what part of the code is causing the problem.

Comment: or `+ QUOTENAME(@objname) + `

Comment: I replaced 'EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;' with 'SELECT @sql;' and I get the same error. I think it's not the code that is causing a problem but something else. Loop is executed around 1000 times but then error appears...

Comment: @AljPra . . . I think the problem is that too many rows are being returned.  You can just do `select distinct` in the query and that should fix your problem.

Comment: As Dan Guzman said, The System.OutOfMemory error is due to returning too large of a results set for SSMS to handle. It is a client-side error, not SQL Server.

Comment: @AljPra . . . And that is happening because your original query is returning all the *rows* that have the GUID instead of just returning the table name and column where they appear.  Actually, I would put in a `group by` and `count(*)` to get the count of matches, but the `distinct` should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like SSMS is falling over, not the server side of things. Basically you are outputting too many results to the screen and Management Studio runs out of available resource to display them.

Your best bet would be to write the values to a temporary table and have a single, final SELECT statement.

Here's a modified copy of my usual search script for you to try. I use this script on LIKE string comparisons on a far larger column set than you are attacking without issue.

### Important note!

Like anything of this sort; this is a resource hog. Best to run it against a test/dev environment and **not against live***

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @value uniqueidentifier  = '<put your guid here>'
      , @sql   varchar(4000)
;

IF Object_ID('tempdb..##results', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##results;
  END
;

-- Temporary table to store SQL statements
CREATE TABLE ##results (
   table_name  sysname
 , column_name sysname
 , hit_count   bigint
);

DECLARE e CURSOR FOR
  SELECT 'INSERT INTO ##results (table_name, column_name, hit_count)'
       + Char(13) + 'SELECT ''' + table_schema + '.' + table_name + ''''
       + Char(13) + '     , ''' + column_name + ''''
       + Char(13) + '     , Count(*)'
       + Char(13) + 'FROM   ' + QuoteName(table_schema) + '.' + Quotename(table_name)
       + Char(13) + 'WHERE  ' + QuoteName(column_name) + ' = ' + QuoteName(@value, '''')
       + Char(13) + 'HAVING Count(*) > 0'
       + Char(13) + ';'
  FROM   information_schema.columns
  WHERE  data_type = 'uniqueidentifier'
;

-- Run SQL statements
OPEN e;
FETCH NEXT FROM e INTO @sql;

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
  BEGIN
    EXEC (@sql);
    FETCH NEXT FROM e INTO @sql;
  END
;
CLOSE e;
DEALLOCATE e;

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

-- Display results
SELECT table_name
     , column_name
     , hit_count
FROM   ##results
ORDER
    BY table_name
     , column_name
;
```

I think you'll find this will work better for you.

Comment: P.S. this script also covers your second question: it will not show any items that have no results (this is covered by the HAVING clause).

Comment: P.P.S. this doesn't *currently* exclude views like your existing script. To do this you just need to add an `INNER JOIN` or `EXISTS` to the `information_schema.columns` table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script I would use:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @TableName SYSNAME,
        @ColumnName SYSNAME,
        @uniqueID nvarchar(100) = 'XXX';

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Results', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Results;

CREATE TABLE #Results 
(
    TableName SYSNAME,
    columnName SYSNAME
);
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR STATIC LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  TableName = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(c.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)),
            ColumnName = QUOTENAME(c.name)
    FROM    sys.columns c
            INNER JOIN sys.tables t
                ON t.object_id = c.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.types ty
                ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
                AND ty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    WHERE   ty.Name = 'uniqueidentifier';

OPEN TableCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 @Table, @Column FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @Columnname + ' = @UniqueID';
    PRINT @SQL;
    INSERT #Results (TableName, ColumnName)
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Table SYSNAME, @Column SYSNAME, @uniqueID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER', @TableName, @ColumnName, @uniqueID;

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName;
END

CLOSE TableCursor;
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;

SELECT  *
FROM    #Results;
```

I have replaced the while loop with a cursor since it will perform better, and I have replaced references to the information schema with references to the SQL Server specific system views since these are more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question to figure how many rows resulted from a query you can use @@rowcount which contains the number of rows that were selected, deleted, updated or inserted by the last operation.

if ( @@rowcount>0)

```
select 'Good'
```

else

```
select 'Nothing'
```